# Assign result of reflect.AppendSlice to pointer

Tags: pointers, go, reflection, types, go-reflect

I have troubles translating this piece of code, which is effectively a left rotate on a slice, into a more generic version which accepts `interface{}` as an input parameter.

```
func rotate(a *[]int, i int) {
    x, b := (*a)[:i], (*a)[i:]
    *a = append(b, x...)
}
```

I have troubles with the final assignment:

```
func rotateSlice(a interface{}, i int) {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(a)
    x, b := v.Elem().Slice(0, i), v.Elem().Slice(i, v.Elem().Len())
    *a = reflect.AppendSlice(b, x)
}
```

The error message is `invalid indirect of a (type {})`. The value of `a` is `interface{}`, hence `*a =` would be to assign the right-hand value to the space where the pointer is pointing to. My call to `AppendSlice` returns `Value` though. I am not sure where the type assertion needs to happen, I suppose on the left-hand side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a` is an `interface{}` not a pointer, so you can't dereference it. Even if you have a pointer to a slice, you can't assigned the result of`reflect.AppendSlice`, because it returns the type `reflect.Value`. You need to set the value via [`Value.Set`](https://godoc.org/reflect#Value.Set).

https://play.golang.org/p/JCF8jsRJ_O

```
func rotateSlice(a interface{}, i int) {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(a).Elem()
    x, b := v.Slice(0, i), v.Slice(i, v.Len())
    v.Set(reflect.AppendSlice(b, x))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Eliminate the use of the reflect package in Go 1.18 and later by using generics:

```
func rotateSlice[T any](a []T, i int) []T {
    x, b := a[:i], a[i:]
    return append(b, x...)
}
```

Call it like this: `x = rotateSlice(x, 2)`

---

Here's now to implement rotate using the reflect package.

Use [Value.Set](https://godoc.org/reflect#Value.Set) to set the value in the slice.

```
func rotateSlice(a interface{}, i int) {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(a).Elem()
    x, b := v.Slice(0, i), v.Slice(i, v.Len())
    v.Set(reflect.AppendSlice(b, x))
}
```

Call the function with a pointer to a slice:

```
a := []string{"a", "b", "c", "d"}
roateSlice(&a, 2)
```

---

[Run all of the examples on the playground](https://go.dev/play/p/flz4Kh5-k2-?v=gotip).